# How to setup Spring Session for Microsoft SQL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting an error when I sign into my Microsoft SQL DB through my `application.properties` file. I currently created the `Spring_Session` tables but for some reason I keep getting the same error where Java says it cannot insert into the table. I made sure I typed in the right server and password but I don't know why it still is not logging in.

**Application Properties:**

```
#MSSQL
jasypt.encryptor.bean=encryptorBean
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://hostname.COM\\RQSHRD31;databaseName=TEST_DB
spring.datasource.username=FED_User
spring.datasource.password=ENC(password)
spring.datasource.databasename=TEST_DB
spring.datasource.databaseschema=APD
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver



#Datasource Info
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
server.servlet.session.timeout = 1500
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

**SpringBoot Application:**

```
@SpringBootApplication      //FETest
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
public class TaddmDevApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Policy.setPolicy(new TaddmPolicy());

        SpringApplication.run(TaddmDevApplication.class, args);     

    }

}
```

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO SPRING_SESSION(PRIMARY_ID, SESSION_ID, CREATION_TIME, LAST_ACCESS_TIME, MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL, EXPIRY_TIME, PRINCIPAL_NAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'SPRING_SESSION'.





Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'SPRING_SESSION'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:259)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft SQL DB collocation may be set to be case-sensitive. In this case, the `Spring_Session` table you created and the `SPRING_SESSION` table for which you are trying to log in from Spring are seen differently from the database.

Try to change the name of table-name from application.property to `Spring_Session`

```
#Datasource Info
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=Spring_Session
```